# NetLogo: Measure maximum distance between 2 patches

Tags: distance, netlogo

my question is really trivial but as a beginner in NetLogo I still cannot find my answer..

I have created a patchy surface (available here: [basic nlogo code](http://ulozto.cz/xqMCmfny/distance-measure-nlogo))

```
to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  reset-ticks
end

;create patchy surface

to setup-patches
  ask n-of 5 patches [ set pcolor green ]
  ask patch 0 0 [ set pcolor yellow ]
  show max-one-of patches with [pcolor = green] [distancexy 0 0]
end
```

I want to **measure the distance between point 0 0 (yellow) and the farthest patch with [pcolor = green].**

To measure the distance in NetLogo, I found two possibilities:

- ***distance*** shows the coordinates of the farthest green patch (not interest in that)
- ***distancexy*** measure the Euclidean distance to my point (what I want)

I tried to create monitors to observe the distance measures using

- max-one-of patches with [pcolor = green] [distancexy 0 0 ] -> returns me patch coordinates and
- [ distance patch 0 0 ] of max-one-of patches [distance myself] -> returns me N/A.

Please, **how to include into my code this distance value?** If I have to create patches-own variable, how can I include it into my code?

Thank you a lot,

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `max`:

```
max [distancexy 0 0] of patches with [pcolor = green]
```

Comment: Thank you @bergant! If I use it like monitor, it works !